# Firebase Dynamic Links App Association File Update

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

Is it possible to update the app-association-file paths when using Firebase's page.link domains? We have several apps in one Firebase project and the app-association-file contains all of them. S o we need to specify certain paths...